# Why is my Bootstrap date-picker not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I tried to use Bootstrap date-picker (https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker), but i can't get it to work.

On jsfiddle everything works like a charm: http://jsfiddle.net/hwuktpt2/

After some failed tests on the actual page, I even tried a blank new page and integrated everything from scratch again. jQuery works, Bootstrap styling works, Datatables works, but I just can't get date-picker to work.

Any suggestions?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/u/bs-3.3.6/jq-2.2.3,jszip-2.5.0,pdfmake-0.1.18,dt-1.10.12,b-1.2.0,b-colvis-1.2.0,b-html5-1.2.0,b-print-1.2.0,fh-3.1.2,se-1.2.0/datatables.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/u/bs-3.3.6/jq-2.2.3,jszip-2.5.0,pdfmake-0.1.18,dt-1.10.12,b-1.2.0,b-colvis-1.2.0,b-html5-1.2.0,b-print-1.2.0,fh-3.1.2,se-1.2.0/datatables.min.js"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.1/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.de.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('.date_picker input').datepicker({
          format: "dd.mm.yyyy",
          todayBtn: "linked",
          language: "de"
        });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .control-label {
            padding-top:7px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="page-header">
            Neues Mobile Device anlegen
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <form class="form-horizontal" name="mobdev_neu" action="mobdev_neu.php" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="mobdev_neu_type" class="col-xs-2 control-label">Type</label>
          <div class="col-xs-10">
            <select id="mobdev_neu_type" class="form-control" name="mobdev_neu_type" REQUIRED>
                <option value="">-- Bitte auswählen --</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="mobdev_neu_imei" class="col-xs-2 control-label">IMEI</label>
          <div class="col-xs-10">
            <input type="text" id="mobdev_neu_imei" class="form-control" name="mobdev_neu_imei" placeholder="Pflichtfeld" REQUIRED>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="mobdev_neu_kaufdatum" class="col-xs-2 control-label">Kaufdatum</label>
          <div class="col-xs-10 date_picker">
            <input type="text" id="mobdev_neu_kaufdatum" class="form-control" name="mobdev_neu_kaufdatum" placeholder="Pflichtfeld">
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wrap the date picker initialize call in a document.ready. This code is running before the dom is finished loading from the look of it. Since JavaScript is interpreted it is run at the time it is read by the browser. Because you're defining the code in the head the body and its contents haven't been loaded yet; so the selector finds no elements to initialize datepicker. If you don't want to use document.ready functionality you could also move the script to the end of the body tag.

```
    $(function(){
        $('.date_picker input').datepicker({
           format: "dd.mm.yyyy",
           todayBtn: "linked",
           language: "de"
        });
    });
```

Comment: Works perfectly fine now...sometimes it's so easy...
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" />
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.5.1/moment.min.js"></script>            
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/3.0.0/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
```

Use these Libraries after using this use below code in you body where you want to make Date field.

```
<div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
<input type='text' class="form-control" name="update_time" placeholder="Update Date"/>
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        var j = jQuery.noConflict();
                        j(function () {
                            j('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
                                format: 'L',
                                disabledHours: true,
                            });
                        });
                    </script>
```